# more than one start statment in the same batch file?

Tags: command-line-interface, batch-file, batch, windows-command-prompt

I wrote the following batch file:

```
start D:\folder1\bin\run.bat
start D:\folder2\bin\run.bat
start D:\folder3\bin\run.bat
start D:\folder4\bin\run.bat
```

It executes the first `start` but then gives me the following error:

```
windows cannot find " D:\folder2\bin" Make sure you type the name
correctly, and then try again. To search for a file, click the
start button,and then click search
```

*Note*: I'm sure the spelling is correct and I put `start
D:\folder2\bin\run.bat` in another file and it executes correctly.

Comment: Try using 'call' instead of 'start'

Comment: @jftuga, `call` is not a substitute for `start`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a stray character or a mismatched quote. There's something about your batch file that you're not showing. Is the space before the "D" in the error message really there (or is it a typo in your question)? If it's real, that and the fact that the error shows the directory but not the filename provides clues to the source of the problem.

Try this to see if it makes a difference:

```
start "title" D:\folder1\bin\run.bat
```

Adding a title like that to each line.

Comment: +1 Start can be finicky when there are multiple `start` lines and the supposedly optional `title` parameter is left out.